# What is the sum of series??

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, mathematica, geometric-progressions

What is the sum of first 50 terms of the series
$$(1\times3)+(3\times5)+(5\times7)+\ldots$$

I had tried to solve this question 
It seems that it is mixed arithmetic series
In which first $A.p$ is $1,3,5\ldots$
Nd other one is $3,5,7\ldots$

But i don't know how to solve it together
Please give me a better solution or approach to solve this problem? 
Tell me a best way to solve 
Such problems

Comment: Try to write down a formula for the $n$th term.

Comment: @saulspatz I don't know

Comment: Can you write down the $k$-th term in the sequence $1,3,5,7,9,\ldots$ (in terms of $k$)?

Comment: What have you tried?  I'm willing to help you learn, but not to do your homework for you.

Comment: I agree with @saulspatz. Consider first not even the summation, but the $n$:th term of the summation (ie. what would be the last term to be summed, if you have $n$ terms?). Then consider the sum over those terms. I'm certain that you will arrive to a solution; algebra will help you lots here.

Comment: I know the formula for nth term of A.P  a+(n--1)..

Comment: @MattiP. Yeah I'm trying but tell me that i have to solve both the series one by one

Comment: Okay so let me give you a little push. It seems like you're summing terms like this:
$$
(2n-1)(2n+1)
$$
, right? So the sum is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1)(2k+1)
$$
Just seeing this sum should give you some idea on how to proceed. Do you have any ideas on how to proceed? What would you think?

Comment: @MattiP. Yupp same like that now plzz tell what i do next

Comment: Hint: you can try manipulating the expression (the one with $k$'s). What do you get as a result?

Comment: @MattiP. My mind got messed up here sum of 50 terms is 1,71,650 how can we get result like that?help me to solve further

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Like Matti P. showed in the comments, the sum is
$$\sum_{n=1}^{50}(2n+1)(2n-1)=\sum_{n=1}^{50}(4n^2-1)=4\sum_{n=1}^{50}n^2-50.$$
I'm sure you can take it from here.

Comment: A long this line, let $P$ be a polynomial. Is it true that all sum of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n P(n)$ can be written as $Q(n)$ for a suitable polynomial $Q$?

Comment: Yes.  Faulhaber's formula. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Answer (score 1):

You have better go through [Falling Factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{49} {\left( {2n + 1} \right)\left( {2n + 3} \right)}  = 4\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{49} {\left( {n + 1/2} \right)\left( {n + 3/2} \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = 4\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{49} {\left( {n + 3/2} \right)^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }  \cr} 
$$
because then the sum telescopes nicely.

In fact we have 
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {n + 3/2} \right)^{\,\underline {\,2\,} }  = {1 \over 3}\left( {\left( {n + 1 + 3/2} \right)^{\,\underline {\,3\,} }  - \left( {n + 3/2} \right)^{\,\underline {\,3\,} } } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 3}\left( {\left( {n + 1 + 3/2} \right)\left( {n + 3/2} \right)\left( {n - 1 + 3/2} \right)
 - \left( {n + 3/2} \right)\left( {n - 1 + 3/2} \right)\left( {n - 2 + 3/2} \right)} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 3}\left( {\left( {n + 1 + 3/2} \right) - \left( {n - 2 + 3/2} \right)} \right)\left( {\left( {n + 3/2} \right)\left( {n - 1 + 3/2} \right)} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {n + 3/2} \right)\left( {n - 1 + 3/2} \right) \cr} 
$$
so that the sum becomes
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{49} {\left( {2n + 1} \right)\left( {2n + 3} \right)}  = 4\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{49} {\left( {n + 3/2} \right)^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = {4 \over 3}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{49} {\left( {\left( {n + 1 + 3/2} \right)^{\,\underline {\,3\,} }  - \left( {n + 3/2} \right)^{\,\underline {\,3\,} } } \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = {4 \over 3}\left( {\left( {50 + 3/2} \right)^{\,\underline {\,3\,} }  - \left( {3/2} \right)^{\,\underline {\,3\,} } } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {4 \over 3}\left( {\left( {50 + 3/2} \right)\left( {49 + 3/2} \right)\left( {48 + 3/2} \right) - \left( {3/2} \right)\left( {1/2} \right)\left( { - 1/2} \right)} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {4 \over {3 \cdot 2^3 }}\left( {103 \cdot 101 \cdot 99 + 3} \right) = {{1029900} \over 6} = 171650 \cr} 
$$

Comment: How did you change $49$ to $50$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: well, you caught a major .. "Delta" in the .. "Antidelta"  :) : added a note to explain it.

Comment: You're saying $ 4\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{49} {\left( {n + 3/2} \right)^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }  = 4\sum\nolimits_{n\, = \,0\,}^{\,50} {\left( {n + 3/2} \right)^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } } \; $?!

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes, "normal sum a,b" $<==>$ "antidelta a,b+1"

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: try with small examples

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: even it is $$
\eqalign{
  & 4\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{49} {\left( {n + 3/2} \right)^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }  = 4\sum\nolimits_{n\, = \,0\,}^{\,50} {\left( {n + 3/2} \right)^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }  = 4\sum\nolimits_{n\, = \,3/2\,}^{\,50 + 3/2} {n^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = {4 \over 3}\left. {\left( {n + 3/2} \right)^{\,\underline {\,3\,} } } \right|_{\,0}^{\,50}  \cr} 
$$

Comment: Doesn't $ \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{49} {\left( {n + 3/2} \right)^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } } \;$differ from $ \sum\nolimits_{n\, = \,0\,}^{\,50} {\left( {n + 3/2} \right)^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }\;  $ by $(51\dfrac12 )(50\dfrac12)$ ?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner  I tried and explain above that the two symbols $\sum\limits_{n = a}^b {} $ (bounds centered above and below) and  $\sum\nolimits_{n\, = \,a\,}^{\,b} {} $ (bounds shifted to the right, are used to mean **two different definitions** of sum, which for integers $a<b$ coincide **provided that** we put "normal sum a,b" <==> "antidelta a,b+1".

Comment: @J.W.Tanner:   Example: $$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{n = 2}^3 {n^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }  = 2^{\,\underline {\,2\,} }  + 3^{\,\underline {\,2\,} }  = 2 \cdot 1 + 3 \cdot 2 = 8  \cr 
  & \sum\nolimits_{n\, = \,2\,}^{\,4} {n^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }  = \left. {{{n^{\,\underline {\,3\,} } } \over 3}} \right|_2^4
  = {1 \over 3}\left( {4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 - 2 \cdot 1 \cdot 0} \right) = 8 \cr} 
$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95095/discussion-between-g-cab-and-j-w-tanner).

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: I followed your suggestion, and recasted my answer in a simpler way.

Comment: I like it better now (+1)